# How to add a multiple marker to a moving location google map,Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a function that adds a marker based on coordinates given to it,but its seems that the simple thing which adding a single position is not working,other than the current position marker to Google map,since the map is keep updating itself over and over the marker will disappeared that's the code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      #map-canvas {
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition, showError);
    }
 }
 function showPosition(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
    mapholder = document.getElementById('map-canvas')
    mapholder.style.height = '250px';
    mapholder.style.width = '500px';

    var myOptions = {
    center:latlon,zoom:14,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl:false,
    navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
    }
    
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"You are here!"});
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}

function initialize() {
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.8903964,35.497148);
 

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'new location!'
  }); 
}
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="getLocation()">
  <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
   <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <a href="Welcome.php" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-left">Search</a>
  </div>
    <div data-role="main">
 <div id="x"></div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div><br/>  
 <button onclick="initialize()">hey</button>
 </div>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're constantly recreating the map and marker. Do those only once, in the initialize function.  Make those global variables, that you can then refer to in your other functions.  Then just do `map.setCenter()` and `marker.setPosition()` to update them when the coordinates change.

Comment: @duncan can you please post an example cause I'me new to this stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So firstly setup the map and marker as global variables:

```
<script>
var map, marker;
...
</script>
```

Refactor your initialize function to create them:

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.8903964, 35.497148);

    var myOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'new location!'
    });
}
```

Then update your showPosition function to update their coordinates:

```
function showPosition(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

    marker.setPosition(latlon);
    marker.setTitle("You are here!");
    map.setCenter(latlon);
}
```

Then amend your HTML so it calls initialize on load, and then getLocation in response to the user clicks.

```
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div><br/>     
    <button onclick="getLocation()">hey</button>
  </body>
```